# Linearising system of ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes, linearization

Suppose we have a system

$$\dot{x}=2x+y^2-1,$$
$$\dot{y}=6x-y^2+1.$$

The system has two equilibria at $(0,1)$ and $(0,-1)$. Now, when we linearise around these equilibria, we find the Jacobian

$$\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 2y \\
6 & -2y
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and find the eigenvalues at each equilibrium.

Now consider a different system
$$\dot{x}=y+2x+x^5,$$
$$\dot{y}=-x-y^5.$$

In this case, we first linearise the system to
$$\dot{x}=y+2x,$$
$$\dot{y}=-x,$$
before finding the equilibria and finding the Jacobian.

My question is, why do we linearise first in the second equation? Is it because the Jacobian would have non-linear terms? But I have seen different systems with non-linear terms where the Jacobian had $y^2$.

If I had a system of equations like
$$\dot{x}=x^3-3x^2+2x-y,$$
$$\dot{y}=x-y,$$
and want to analyse the stability of the equilibria, should I linearise first or just find the equilibria and find the Jacobian normally?

Comment: Linearisation is an approximation. Sometimes, the system for which you want to find the critical points are so complicated, that it is impossible to do it without linearisation.

Comment: You are always lineralizing _around_ an equilibrium (or some other point). In the second case, you linearized around $x_0=0$ and $y_0=0$. Otherwise,  your linearization should look different (i.e. contain the terms $x_0$ and $y_0$). A clearer notation would help here, e.g. to set $\Delta x=x-x_0$. Your linearized system would then have states $\Delta x$, while the Jacobian would depend on $x_0$.

Comment: Also: a linearization corresponds to a first order Taylor series approximation around an equilibrium. That you do it around an equilibrium guarantees you that the zeroth order (constant) terms of the approximation vanish. If you want to find the equilibrium after the "linearization", you however have to keep the zeroth order terms during the "linearization", because you need them to determine the equilibria.

Comment: You will thus find out that the two options in your last question are nearly equivalent from what you actually do mathematically (try it). First finding equilibria is however a bit easier since you can find the EV of the Jacobian then numerically.